# Setting Exchange Mailbox ACL using Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to figure out how to do this kind of thing, but using PowerShell calls (from C#). We are moving to Exchange 2010 and my old code doesn't want to work, hence the PowerShell.

```
IExchangeMailbox exMb = (IExchangeMailbox)userDe.NativeObject;
IADsSecurityDescriptor securityDescriptor = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)exMb.MailboxRights;
IADsAccessControlList acl = (IADsAccessControlList)securityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl;
AccessControlEntry ace = new AccessControlEntry();
...
...
```

I've got the mailbox OK using:

```
        using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
            powershell.AddParameter("Identity", username);

            runspace.Open();
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            return powershell.Invoke()[0];
        }
```

But if I then pass the result to a similar method to get the ACL so I can start modifying that, like this

```
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.AddCommand("Get-Acl");
        powershell.AddArgument(mailbox);

        runspace.Open();
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        return powershell.Invoke()[0];
    }
```

...I get

> The term 'Get-Acl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

...coming out in the logs. I also tried 'Get-ACL' in case it was case sensitive but I think the first version is correct.

I also tried Get-MailboxPermission but the docs for that say it doesn't even have a return type, so it wouldn't give me an object to manipulate afterwards.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out eventually:

```
powershell.AddCommand("Add-MailboxPermission");
powershell.AddParameter("Identity", mailboxIdentity); 
powershell.AddParameter("User", groupName); 
powershell.AddParameter("AccessRights", "FullAccess"); 
powershell.AddParameter("InheritanceType", "All");
```